# Firefox 57 Not Asking To Save Passwords (certain sites only)

Tags: firefox, passwords, autocomplete, password-management

According to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers/21348793#21348793, browsers ignore autocomplete="off" for login/password fields.  But there are still sites where Firefox is not asking to remember my password and it's driving me crazy.

For example:

https://www.benefits.ml.com

https://online.citi.com/US/login.do

Comment: This is probably a desired behavior from the website developers; there are many modern working ways to achieve it and I don't understand why you need to save *all* passwords? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I've just created a super simple add-on that can help.
It will create dummy `form` with two inputs and a `submit` button. After you click it, Firefox will ask you to store those credentials.

**Save my Password** for Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-my-password/

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you have to go north to get south.  Firefox would not save the log in for one website. I went to Chrome and was able to save it there. Then I opened the saved log ins list in Firefox (under Options, Privacy and Security). I clicked on "import" and told it to import from Chrome. Voila! My saved log in is now in Firefox and works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

This answer does not provide an explanation to what you are seeing.
But it may help you getting FF to remember the passwords it is currently not, so you may take it as a workaround.

[This site](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/firefox-dont-remember-yahoo-mail-and-hotmail-password/) provides 4 different ways of forcing FF to remember passwords.

A long time I suffered from the same problem you are having now, and not finding the cause/solution, I used several of the proposed methods, and they worked quite well.

PS: I did not try any of these for FF>=57.